# using QuasirandomGenerator (for dummies)

Tags: random, cuda, numbers, generator

I am a newbi to CUDA and I am struggling to generate random numbers in my kernels.

I know there are different implementations, and, what is more, in the SDK 4.1 there is an example of the Niederreiter Quasirandom Sequence Generator.

I don't know where to start... I am a bit sad and feeling like a dummy...

Could anyone please please make a simple and silly example of using the Niederreiter Quasirandom Sequence Generator (SKD code example)? I would really apreciate it.
For example, creating a vector and filling it with random numbers (each thread filling a vector position).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The quasirandomGenerator sample in the SDK does pretty much what you're asking, it takes a region of memory and fills it with quasirandom numbers.

That said, I think you'd be better off using cuRAND, it's Sobol' instead of Niederreiter but unless you have a specific reason for preferring the later you will find it easier to use. For examples of how to use it you should look in the MonteCarloCURAND set of samples:

- EstimatePiQ shows how to allocate a region on GPU memory and fill it with Sobol' numbers
- EstimatePiInlineQ shows how to generate one number at a time within another kernel

The samples ending in P use pseudo-random generators.

Comment: Thank you, I have used cuRAND and it perfectly fulfills my needs. In fact, I was very happy with the results I obtained. But when I use this library with the feval function of the Parallel Computing Toolbox of Matlab I have wrong and unexpected results. Some extrange behaviors appears... So I want to try another generator to compare.

Comment: The numbers generated in cuRAND are the standard Sobol' sequence, so it's more likely your doing something wrong elsewhere I'm afraid (in your calling from Matlab perhaps).

Comment: I think there is something with the parallel computing toolbox maybe... My CUDA implementation works well without MATLAB (when I call my kernel directly from host code), but when the call is made through Matlab I get extrage results.... The calling from Matlab is simple, I can not do anything wrong there.... http://www.mathworks.es/help/toolbox/distcomp/feval.html

Comment: Do you know any other easy-to-use random generator I could use?

Comment: Are you using feval properly, have you created the gpuArrays properly? And are you gathering before looking at them on CPU?

Comment: You don´t need to create gpuArrays, the arrays can be MATLAB ones... (example o = feval(k, rand(100, 1), rand(100, 1));) from here http://www.mathworks.es/help/toolbox/distcomp/bslohnr-1.html           I am gathering, if you do not gather you don´t see anything...      I have tried simple code and it works... And my simulation code works... the problems is the meaning of the results I get, they are not reasonable...  I would like to try another random generator

Comment: Why not post a question with your code to see why it is not working? cuRAND is unlikely to be the source of the problem here! If you want to try another random number generator then take a look at the Sobol' sample if the Niederreiter sample doesn't help you.

Comment: I am sorry, I can not post my code, it is my research work... so it is confidential. I know cuRAND is not the problem. I think the Parallel Computing Toolbox is. So I want to try another random number generator, this is why I post here. I found the Niederreiter Quasirandom Sequence Generator complicated to use. Thank you very much! I am going to try the Sobol!