# How can I use CURAND_RNG_QUASI_SOBOL32 generator using device API? CUDA

Tags: random, cuda

A snippet of my task is to generate, let's say, 256 quasi-random numbers using CUDA. I've read cuRAND [docs](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/curand/) and from there I've [learnt](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/curand/device-api-overview.html#quasirandom-sequences) that I need to use a set of direction vectors, which I can get using `curandGetDirectionVectors32` function. But the problem is that I still can not understand what is 'set of direction vectors'. Especially how to use it, how to limit its length etc.

Also there's no example in [Device API Examples](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/curand/device-api-overview.html#device-api-example) with Sobol's generator. And there's no working example in google. I've found [some explanation](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/539775/) but `scrambled_sobol_v_host` is not declared in that scope and unclear for me.

So, my question is could anyone, please, provide me with tiny working example of usage of this generator?

And I have troubles with understanding difference between Sobol's generator and scrambled Sobol's generator.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you'll have to track down this paper: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=10344456650745414052&hl=en&as_sdt=0,33

Comment: and go through this one http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~hcc8471/ssobol.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direction vectors are the seeding method for that number generator. For implementation you should be able to follow [using QuasirandomGenerator (for dummies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292658/using-quasirandomgenerator-for-dummies)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your comments!
By the way (I understand it's kind out of topic, but It seems like you are the person, who probably could make it clear for me), should I use QRNG only with Monte Carlo simulations or not? Is it okay to simulate Monte Carlo with PRNG?

Comment: [Professional CUDA C Programming, p.350](https://books.google.ru/books?id=o_FjBAAAQBAJ&pg=PP1&lpg=PP1&dq=Professional+CUDA+C+Programming+John+Cheng,+Max+Grossman,+Ty+McKercher&source=bl&ots=ApdTruDbhY&sig=4DG7afoCfPBwGkEWL-WmBZV6MrI&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=B-TpVL6rB6f7ygPAnIGYAw&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAQ) covers the answer to question of difference between usage of both QRNG and PRNG. Now it's cear.